# Почему зафиксированный блок не зависим от относительного позиционирование?

Tags: css, position

**Resource:**
[Ссылка](https://codepen.io/assylzhan91/pen/QeaoYd)

**Question:**
Интересно, а почему фиксированное позиционирование не зависит от относительного?
Ведь,  в данном исходнике меню зафиксирована, но когда задаю менюшке `width:100%`, она не подстраивается под ширину `.container`, даже если она `position: relative`, Ребята а как исправить это?

Comment: Достаточно найти описание свойства http://htmlbook.ru/css/position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При задании `position: fixed`, блок позиционируется оносительно области видимости (окна браузера), а не относительно блока с `position: relative;`.

Чтобы привязать к относительно позиционированному блоку, для текущего блока используйте `position: absolute`.

[Результат на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/wVpZQp)

.

**UPD:** чтобы меню не уезжало вверх, следует применить `position: sticky`

[Результат на Codepen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/QeaRjJ?editors=1100)

Comment: Ширина менюшки должна  подстроиться под контейнер(в моем случае 500px), и при этом зафиксирована(про скролле, она не подвижная)!  А у Вас  меню уходит вверх)

Comment: @John, чтобы меню не уезжало вверх, следует применить `position: sticky`. Результат на CodePen: http://bit.ly/2KgAqFj

Comment: Благодарю! теперь-то буду знать